# close multiple cmd window using batch file in windows 7 pro. 

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, taskbar

When I run a batch file `for /l %%x in (1,1,270) do ( start "" java -cp ... Client)` in cmd 270 window will open. These all windows are individual I just want to close all these window by using another batch file...

I am using windows 7 prof.

I tried the taskbar property combine, it does not work.
i want close these all java window using batchfile
[image: taskbar]
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `taskkill` provided that all the java processes are named the same thing, lets say `java.exe` for this

```
taskkill /im java.exe /f
```

which will close all the windows named `java.exe`.

Comment: I just interested to know that is there any code that close all the taskbar item.

Comment: No problem. You need to get the process name of the taskbar item, then use `taskkill` on the name. Get the process name through task manager, right click on the app and go to process.